# Sequelize postgresql datetime math in where clause using joined table field

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

Yeah, it's a mouthful. I don't understand why every time I use some lame js framework (i.e sequelize in this case) I find it's constraints within hours. Enough ranting.

Versions:
PostgreSQL 11.10 (Debian 11.10-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit

"sequelize": "^5.22.3"

I have two tables that I need to inner join to get all the rows of the first that haven't been updated in a period of time specified by a field in the second. in postgresql it this statement works. I have modified my code snippets to simplify so apologize for any syntax errors.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM order_header h,
     sla_shipping_rules r
WHERE h.shipping_method = r.shipping_method
  AND date_part('epoch', h.updated_at) + r.secondary_tax_timeout_hour < date_part('epoch', now());
```

I don't think this is feasible in sequelize but if anybody has a solution I would love to be proven wrong. I am stuck with sequelize forever at this point. I have tried about 100 different options. The latest few are below.

The one below results in "sla_shipping_rules"."secondary_tax_timeout_hour" < NaN in the where clause getting sent to postgresql

```
const getPendingOrders = () => OrderHeader.findAll({
  where: {
    '$sla_shipping_rules.secondary_tax_timeout_hour$': { [Op.lt]: Math.floor(new Date()) - Math.floor(sequelize.col('OrderHeader.updated_at')) },
  },
  include: {
    attributes: ['secondary_tax_timeout_hour'],
    model: SlaShippingRules,
    as: 'sla_shipping_rules',
    on: { shipping_method: { [Op.eq]: sequelize.col('OrderHeader.shipping_method') } },
    required: true,
  },
});
```

The one below also results in "sla_shipping_rules"."secondary_tax_timeout_hour" < NaN in the where clause that gets sent to postgresql

```
const getPendingOrders = () => OrderHeader.findAll({
  where: {
    '$sla_shipping_rules.secondary_tax_timeout_hour$': { [Op.lt]: sequelize.fn('date_part', 'epoch', sequelize.fn('now')) - sequelize.fn('date_part', 'epoch', sequelize.col('OrderHeader.updated_at')) },
  },
  include: {
    attributes: ['secondary_tax_timeout_hour'],
    model: SlaShippingRules,
    as: 'sla_shipping_rules',
    on: { shipping_method: { [Op.eq]: sequelize.col('OrderHeader.shipping_method') } },
    required: true,
  },
});
```

The one below results in an invalid column name for 'epoch' I tried a bunch of different combinations of quotes also I just can't make js align with what postgresql wants.

```
const getPendingOrders = () => OrderHeader.findAll({
  where: {
    '$sla_shipping_rules.secondary_tax_timeout_hour$': { [Op.lt]: sequelize.literal('date_part(`epoch`, "OrderHeader"."updated_at") - date_part(`epoch`, now())') },
  },
  include: {
    attributes: ['secondary_tax_timeout_hour'],
    model: SlaShippingRules,
    as: 'sla_shipping_rules',
    on: { shipping_method: { [Op.eq]: sequelize.col('OrderHeader.shipping_method') } },
    required: true,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to replace back-ticks with single quotes like this:

```
where: {
    '$sla_shipping_rules.secondary_tax_timeout_hour$': { [Op.lt]: sequelize.literal('date_part(\'epoch\', "OrderHeader"."updated_at") - date_part(\'epoch\', now())') },
  }
```